# How to establish connection between IBM cloud in android studio

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I want to create an android application which can access data from IBM cloud and display value in android application.[In java language] but i have no idea how to connect my android application to IBM cloud.
Please can explain me about IBM connection.

I go through following page also, https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/blob/master/README.md

Thanks,

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The watson tutorial you linked is pretty much describing what to do, so you would have to specify what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instructions mentioned in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/chatbot-watson-android), You will learn how easy it is to build an IBM Watson powered ChatBot running on Android and using Watson Assistant (formerly Conversation),Text-to-Speech, Speech-to-Text Services on IBM Cloud (an open standards, cloud platform for building, running, and managing apps and services).

For step-by-step instructions, refer this tutorial - [Build a voice-enabled Android chatbot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-android-watson-chatbot)

The tutorial walks you through the process of defining intents and entities and building a dialog flow for your chatbot to respond to customer queries. You will learn how to enable Speech to Text and Text to Speech services for easy interaction with the Android app.